# Create Temporary Webpage with Randomly Generated URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

Alright, so I'm trying to write a little app that creates a temporary webpage (kinda) and I can't figure out what it is that needs to happen for this to work exactly.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do and that should help. Basically, I want to have `app.com` and when a user goes there there's a button like "Make temp page" or something. Click that and then it makes a random URL extension and puts the visitor there, so something like `app.com/admin/xxyy12`. Now the user can give the URL `app.com/xxyy12` to someone and they can navigate there and send data back and forth between each other, my thinking was via WebSockets. So I want the person that made the link to be an admin of sorts and when they leave that "admin" page I want it and `app.com/xxyy12` to self destruct basically, no one can go there and that route doesn't exist anymore.

Is this possible and what technologies should I look into to accomplish this? I thought it would be cool to do this all in-browser with no server, which kills some security but I don't really care about that. I'm not really sure how to create these "temporary" pages either. I figured WebSockets would come in handy to send data between the person that created the link and the client visiting it, and I figured the main page `app.com` would need a socket to the user at `app.com/admin/xxyy12` to determine when it disconnects. Also, I considered html parameters to basically make a "temporary" URL that would just read the param and then that would wire the client to the URL creator. There would also need to be a way of storing what active temporary pages exist.

I recognize that this question is rather vague but I suppose I'm just looking for ideas of how to accomplish this and what technologies would be recommended. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: you need http, not sockets, because you need to serve the page. or rewrite all the relative urls, b ut that could be hard, especially deep in CSS imports...

Comment: if you don't need navigation, but just a single page, then you can use dataURLs embeded in the html, then just pluck `document.documentElement.outerHTML`, and on the viewer, `bigIframe.contentDocument.write( theOuterHTML)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get what I wanted. I basically make a random string and add it to the end of the url with a '#' at the beginning. Then I can use location.hash.substring to pull off the random string. This string acts as "unique" identifier to connect peers together.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to implement.
I would use:
Node.js on the server with
express.js  and maybe socket.io if needed

In express:
create routes to serve pages

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
//render homepage here
});
app.post('/', function(req,res){
// handle creating temp pages here and
// redirect client to that page
// save ID of the page to db
});
app.get('/:pageId', function(req,res){
// handle rendering the temp page by ID
});
app.post('/destroy', function(req,res){
// remove page from db
});
```

You could post from client on javascript unload message i think, so maybe no need for websockets but im not sure how reliable that is

I hope this helps